# Stop transaction in a thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, transactions

I use a **TransactionScope** in a **thread** to dump data in my SQL Server database.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Dump data in database
    scope.Complete();
}
```

The transaction is a long transaction (~40 seconds) because the large amount of data. This is normal.

When I do an `Abort()` to stop the thread during this transaction, SQL Server seems to be locked for a few minutes.

What is happening and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply said: you can not.

> Server seems to be locked during a few
>   minutes.

No. SQL Server is busy undoing your transaction. It is optimized fully to COMMIT transactions, not to undo them. Undoing LARGE updates is a SLOW operation. Depending on your server layout and the amount of data it can take some minutes or even hours.

All you can do is... not rollback / abort. Or wait.

Comment: Ok, thank you ! If I kill my c# program, I have the same behaviour

Comment: As it should be. Any abort client side - and a kill of the program obviously is one - will trigger a rollback on the server side. The transaction was not commited ergo it is aborted.

Comment: it's obvious, if you kill the program the tran remains not committed and will be aborted.